# Face detection + Image morphing

Tags: php, image-recognition, face-detection, morphing

I am looking to create a site like photofunia.com where basically you can apply a large number of effects to an image. I am wondering if someone can guide me in the right direction as to the technology which must be used to achieve the same? Also, are there any open-source commandline utilities available to create such images?

I don't think Image::Magick or GD will be able to handle such effects. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post may help: http://svay.com/blog/index/post/2009/06/19/Face-detection-in-pure-PHP-%28without-OpenCV%29